# Which format to choose for storing and displaying data in D3.js dynamically?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, d3.js, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project with my Raspberry Pi where a sensor continuously collects data. I want to store that data in a specific format (SQL, CSV, JSON or something else) and then visualize it on a simple page with D3.js

I have thought of a few ways, for example using SQLite or MySQL to create a DB and store the data, then simply convert this sql DB into a JSON or CSV file in order to display it. But so far I have not come up with a proper solution on how to store, convert (if needed) and display the data dynamically without using up too many resourced or time.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your intent to store the data locally, or to push it up to a remote server?

Comment: This seems too open-ended and opinion-based to be a good fit for SO. It really depends on the data and how its going to be used. But if the data is not terribly complex and it only used for d3 is would say just keep it in JSON format. Thats the format D3 wants it in and most programming languages (especially JS) make it real easy to work with JSON

Comment: @dylanwatt the data will be stored locally.

Comment: @dan08: as for the data, it's pretty much just a the timestamp (of the entry), and two datasets (integers) that represent the respective values that are gathered by the sensor. The problem I have read about JSON data is that it's not really good for appending new data (meaning creating an ever-upding JSON list) because it's quite time-consuming since you have to load the entire JSON list into the program first. (my googling may be faulty though and this may not be the case).

Answer (score 2):

Considering you don't need any of the features a database offers, (you're just writing to a single table from a single process), I would probably just write out to a csv. That's going to have the smallest footprint. You can process the csv into json when you dump the data off, if you need.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest creating DB's in SQL and then convert them into either flat or nested JSON (flat is usually easier to work with, so I suggest flat) and then plugging them into your d3 file. That's how I work and I feel many others would agree.